# Trouble With State/Capital Matching Program In VB

Tags: vb.net

Alright, so the program is set up where you have a set of radio buttons with 5 states, and another set of 5 with 5 capitals. There's a button which tells you if they match or not. However I have to do it a certain way where clicking a radio button assigns a variable to both 'strCapital' and 'strChoice' and you compare them to see if they match.

I've tried to figure everything out (since it sounds easy in theory) but I've hit a wall.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain

Dim strCapital As String
Dim strChoice As String

Dim strLittleRock As String
Dim strSpringfield As String
Dim strFrankfort As String
Dim strSalem As String
Dim strMadison As String

Private Sub radArkansas_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radArkansas.CheckedChanged
    strCapital = strLittleRock
End Sub

Private Sub radIllinois_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radIllinois.CheckedChanged
    strCapital = strSpringfield
End Sub

Private Sub radSpringfield_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radSpringfield.CheckedChanged
    strChoice = strSpringfield
End Sub

Private Sub btnVerify_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnVerify.Click
    If strCapital = strChoice Then
        lblMsg.Text = "Correct"
    ElseIf strCapital <> strChoice Then
        lblMsg.Text = "Incorrect"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub radLittleRock_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
   radLittleRock.CheckedChanged
    strChoice = strLittleRock
End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT:** Also I forgot to mention the main problem which is always a bad thing. Basically whenever I run it and enter something incorrect (checking Arkansas and Springfield for example) it always says it's correct.

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, you can't combine multiple tags to create a single concept.  The tags `[visual]` and `[basic]` together aren't the same thing as the single `[vb.net]` tag.  Also, tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (visual, basic, state, solution) will not help categorize it.  **Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!**

Comment: @charles Sorry about that.

Comment: Have you tried setting any breakpoints so you can see what is going on?  I have a feeling that the `CheckedChanged` event isn't what you think it is...

Comment: @Douglas Barbin 

I double clicked on the individual radio buttons on the designer assuming it meant if it's selected it would do so and so. Since I wanted to make it so if say 'radArkansas' is selected the variable would mean 'strArkansas' if that makes sense.

Also as a side question what do you mean by breakpoints?

Comment: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets5p6.html

Comment: Set a breakpoint on each event, and see if more than one event is getting fired when you click on `radArkansas`.

Comment: @ Douglas Barbin

I don't know where exactly I need to put them, but I tried following your link but it didn't really help when I tried doing it.

Comment: **study** the link provided - debugging is a very important aspect of programming.  a breakpoint will show you why it doesnt work (see also MSDN re: radio buttons).  RBs can get 2 change events - when the old one changes from off to on and then another for the one going off->on.  you are better off evaluating the selection when they click the button.

Comment: @Plutonix

Well I played around with it and I know that it's because it skips over the Else regardless of the answer, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: @user3538001 - Here's a tip to help you find out what's wrong (although using breakpoints should have worked).  Inside each of your CheckChanged event, put a MessageBox.Show call.  Then run your program and check one of the radio buttons.  Here's an additional hint:  When you check the Arkansas radio button, the Illinois radio button is _unchecked_.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar... you can modify this code:

Private Sub btnAmIRight_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAmIRight.Click
        ' displays if submission is correct

```
    ' declare variables
    Dim strAmIRight As String
    Dim dblMatch As Double


    If rbtnAlabama.Checked = True And rbtnMontgomery.Checked = True Then
        dblMatch = 1
    ElseIf rbtnAlaska.Checked = True And rbtnJuneau.Checked = True Then
        dblMatch = 1
    ElseIf rbtnArizona.Checked = True And rbtnPhoenix.Checked = True Then
        dblMatch = 1
    ElseIf rbtnArkansas.Checked = True And rbtnLittleRock.Checked = True Then
        dblMatch = 1
    ElseIf rbtnCalifornia.Checked = True And rbtnSacramento.Checked = True Then
        dblMatch = 1
    ElseIf rbtnColorado.Checked = True And rbtnDenver.Checked = True Then
        dblMatch = 1
    ElseIf rbtnConnecticut.Checked = True And rbtnHartford.Checked = True Then
        dblMatch = 1
    ElseIf rbtnDelaware.Checked = True And rbtnDover.Checked = True Then
        dblMatch = 1
    ElseIf rbtnFlorida.Checked = True And rbtnTallahassee.Checked = True Then
        dblMatch = 1
    ElseIf rbtnGeorgia.Checked = True And rbtnAtlanta.Checked = True Then
        dblMatch = 1
    Else
        dblMatch = 0

    End If

    ' assign code to variable
    If dblMatch = 1 Then
        strAmIRight = "Correct"
    ElseIf dblMatch = 0 Then
        strAmIRight = "Try Again"
    End If

    ' display result
    lblResult.Text = strAmIRight.ToString

End Sub
```